# Bunch of errors when I hover my mouse over install button in a live session

Tags: boot, xubuntu, live-usb

I am trying to install xubuntu 22.04 LTS jammy jellyfish through a usb stick. Errors come up in the live session.This video explains it all
https://youtu.be/NDlbZUZrWvg

You can hear me click randomly, so that you can make out when I'm clicking and when I'm not. I just place my mouse on the button without even clicking.At the end of the video, you can see the error message jumping between 3 texts. After waiting for a few mins: https://imgur.io/a/eHgOgVu

After removing the splash line in the grub menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXWJw.jpg

Even after disabling nouveau drivers, enabling/disabling secure boot, nothing happens. I have checksum'd the image. Tried reflashing the usb 20 times, used balena etcher instead of rufus,but to no avail.

My laptop specs:
Brand: Asus
Intel i3 7th gen
Nvidia GeForce 920mx with an igpu
4GB ram
1Tb HDD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: The errors are probably unrelated to the actual problem which is the desktop not loading. So, use the "safe graphics" option.

Comment: @karel unfortunately i don't think it does

Comment: @ChanganAuto safe graphics mode takes too much time to load and no, it didn't help the screen freezes when I press install Ubuntu :(

Comment: I think it does answer your question. There's a huge amount of information in the answers to this question. The information in my answer took me years to amass and compile, and I still add to it whenever I find new content for it at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Well it "does" boot because I can make it to the install button right? It's next, what happens after trying to click the button